# How to solve a version problem in urllib3?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib3

So, i'm trying to make a web scraping using python like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3744/'
response = requests.get(url)
raw_html = response.text 

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
print(raw_html)
```

and here's the error:

`line 57, in <module>     raise RuntimeError('Requests dependency \'urllib3\' must be version >= 1.21.1, < 1.22!') RuntimeError: Requests dependency 'urllib3' must be version >= 1.21.1, < 1.22!`

I tried to do everything, downloading different versions of urllib3, but there is a major problem because Selenium and Requests require different versions of urllib3.

checkout this:

*after pip install urllib=1.23 for selenium*

Collecting urllib3==1.23
Downloading urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.3/133.3 kB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: urllib3
Attempting uninstall: urllib3
Found existing installation: urllib3 2.0.2
Uninstalling urllib3-2.0.2:
Successfully uninstalled urllib3-2.0.2
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
requests2 2.16.0 requires urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1, but you have urllib3 1.23 which is incompatible.
selenium 4.9.1 requires urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26, but you have urllib3 1.23 which is incompatible.

and after trying to update urrlib3...

Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in "dir"
Collecting urllib3
Using cached urllib3-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (123 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3
Attempting uninstall: urllib3
Found existing installation: urllib3 1.23
Uninstalling urllib3-1.23:
Successfully uninstalled urllib3-1.23
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
requests2 2.16.0 requires urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1, but you have urllib3 2.0.2 which is incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3744/'
response = requests.get(url)
raw_html = response.text 

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
print(raw_html)
```

does use `requests` to just download certain file from given URL, you might use [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) instead, it is part of standard library so you do not need install anything, consider following simple example

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.example.com'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    parsed = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
print(parsed.find("h1"))
```

gives output

```
<h1>Example Domain</h1>
```

Note: for brevity sake I just print h1 rather than whole page

Answer (score 1):

First update pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Install current version of requests, which is 2.31.0:

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests
```

You seem to have 4.9.1, the latest Selenium version.

There should be no need to mess with specific versions or urllib.